# Correct definition of explicit default constructor with enum and template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, enums, explicit

I have a base class `Method` with subclasses.

```
auto harmonic_force = [](const double& q, const double& k){return -k*q;};
enum SplittingAB{ SS,L42 };

class Method
{
public:
    ~Method() = default;
    virtual void evolute( std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> &qp, int T) const = 0;
};


template <typename Function>
class MiddleO : public Method{
public:
    MiddleO() = default;
    explicit MiddleO(SplittingAB mmo_=SS, const double& a_=-1.0, const double& b_=1.0, const Function& force_=harmonic_force, const double& k_=1.0, const double& gamma_=1.0, const double& kBT_=1.0);

    void evolute( std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> &qp,  int T) const override;

    std::string get_name(SplittingAB m) const {
        switch (m){
            case SplittingAB:: SS:{
                return "MethodsMiddleO_SS";
            }
            case SplittingAB ::L42:{
                return "MethodsMiddleO_L42";
            }
        }
    }
private:
    SplittingAB  mmo;
    const double k{}, gamma{}, kBT{}, a{}, b{};
    double L = 1.0;
    Function&  force;
};
```

My defintion of the constructor is as fallow:

```
template<typename Function>
MiddleO<Function>::MiddleO(SplittingAB mmo_, const double &a_, const double &b_, const Function &force_,
                       const double &k_, const double &gamma_, const double &kBT_)
    : Method(), mmo(mmo_), a(a_), b(b_), force(force_), k(k_), gamma(gamma_), kBT(kBT_) { L=b-a; }
```

1. I get the error `binding reference of type ‘<lambda(double, double)>&’ to ‘const<lambda(double, double)>’ discards qualifiers`. I cannot understand how I should initialize the force correctly.
2. I also get the remark `Constructor does not initialize these fields: mmo`

EDIT:
In my `main()` function I wrote:

```
auto cos_force = [](double q, const double k){return -q*q*q*k - 5.0*cos(1+5.0*q);};
int main(){
     double a = -3.5;
     double b = 3.5;

    double const k = 1.0;
    double const gamma = 1.0;
    double const kBT=1.0;
    std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> qp;
    qp.reserve(T+1);
    qp.emplace_back(0.0,0.1);

    SplittingAB sm = SS;
    MiddleO<decltype(cos_force)> obj(sm, a,  b, cos_force , k, gamma,kBT);
   ...
}
```

Comment: This compiles fine. Can you share the instantiation that gives the error?

Comment: The compiler argument `const Function &force_` would have to be changed to `Function &force_` in order to bind this reference -- or change the field to `const Function& force;`.

Comment: I get the error with `SplittingAB sm = SS; ` and 
   `MiddleO<decltype(cos_force)> obj(sm, a,  b, cos_force , k, gamma,kBT);` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Then please provide the definition of `cos_force`. See how to make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1

The compiler rightly reports an error since you are trying to intialize a `Function&` with a `Function const&`. If allowed, it won't preserve the `const`-ness of the original object.

Unless performance is a proven issue for your use case, change

```
Function&  force;
```

to

```
Function  force;
```

#### Issue 2

Add code to initialize the member.

```
template<typename Function>
MiddleO<Function>::MiddleO(SplittingAB mmo_, const double &a_, const double &b_,
                           const Function &force_, const double &k_,
                           const double &gamma_, const double &kBT_)
    : Method(), mmo(mmo_), a(a_), b(b_), force(force_), k(k_),
      gamma(gamma_), kBT(kBT_), mmo(SS) { L=b-a; }
                             // ^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps the compiler is complaininig about the default constructor.

Also,

```
MiddleO() = default;
```

is not right. That doesn't provide a way for the reference member to be initialized. The compiler should have reported an error for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, why is it not enough to write `mmo(mmo_)` to initialize the field.

Comment: @Suslik, sorry, that was a mistake on my part. Perhaps the comiler is complaining about the default constructor.

Comment: aha, thank you. Your first hint solved one of my problems.